# $\sin x + \sin2x + \sin3x = \cos x + \cos2x + \cos3x$

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry

> Find the number of solutions to $\sin x+\sin2x+\sin3x=\cos x+\cos2x+\cos3x$ with $x\in[0,2\pi)$

I tried to solve it by doing this:-

$$2\sin(2x)\cos x + \sin(2x) = 2\cos(2x)\cos x + \cos(2x)$$

$$\sin(2x) (2\cos x+1) = \cos(2x) (2\cos x + 1)$$

$$
 \sin(2x)  = \cos(2x)$$

$$
 2\cos x\sin x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x$$

$$
 2\cos x\sin x + 2\sin^2 x - 1 = 0$$

$$
 2\sin x(\cos x + \sin x) -1=0$$

$$
 2\sin x(2\sin x) -1=0$$

$$
 4\sin^2 x = 0$$

$$
 \sin^2 x = (\frac{1}{2})^2$$

$$
 \sin^2 x = \sin^2 (\frac{\pi}{6})$$

Now by using $x = nπ -\frac{\pi}{6}$ I got 4 solutions between $0,2\pi$. But the answer is 6. Where I did wrong. Please don't mind for mistakes and answer ASAP. THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a lot more help if your questions are easy to read.

Comment: Also I think it's impolite to say 'answer ASAP'. Kindly note that this site objective is not merely to just answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

You have also $$2\cos{x}+1=0,$$ which gives another two roots.

Because $$\sin2x(2\cos{x}+1)=\cos2x(2\cos{x}+1)$$ it's
$$\sin2x(2\cos{x}+1)-\cos2x(2\cos{x}+1)=0$$ or
$$(2\cos{x}+1)(\sin2x-\cos2x)=0$$ and we obtain:
$$2\cos{x}+1=0$$ or
$$\sin2x-\cos2x=0.$$

Comment: Explain please..

Comment: @DiyaSarkar You divided out $2\cos x+1$ at one point, but you can't do that if $2\cos x+1=0$, so you have to check those roots too.

Comment: So what should I do there???

Comment: @Diya Sarkar I added something. See now.